# Add New Item to Already Bound ListView in ASP Net (Unable to set DataKeys/FieldName)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview, listviewitem

My overall goal is to add fake/unbound items to a listview control (for final HTML Table output reasons). This is a code behind solution. Users will not be adding items as it will be outputted in a rigid table.

I have looked at several examples and while this is easy for a dropdown it is not for listview.

The code below works without error, but my item is not shown on runtime. I think the class is not setting the item fieldname correctly, but I can't figure out the right syntax to fix it.

```
ColumnNameAList.DataSource = PeriodDataView
ColumnNameAList.DataBind()

Dim test As New Example1("ColumnNameA")

Dim newItem As New ListViewDataItem(ColumnNameAList.Items.Count, ColumnNameAList.Items.Count)
newItem.DataItem = test

ColumnNameAList.Items.Insert(ColumnNameAList.Items.Count, newItem)
ColumnNameAList.Items.Add(newItem)
```

Here is the Example1 class that is supposed to set the DataValueField:

```
Public Class Example1
Public Sub New(ColumnNameA__1 As String)
    ColumnNameA = ColumnNameA__1
End Sub

Private m_ColumnNameA As String

Public Property ColumnNameA() As String
    Get
        Return m_ColumnNameA
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_ColumnNameA = value
    End Set
End Property

End Class
```

This outputs my original datasource list, but not the added item.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <td>
        <%# Eval("ColumnNameA")%>

    </td>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: At what point are you invoking your insertion code? It should be executed as a listener on the [`ListView.DataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.databound.aspx) event, otherwise databinding will empty any elements you have populated manually.

Comment: I'm working in someone else's code and they have a custom sub that then has the "ColumnNameAList.DataBind()" called. I placed the manual insertion code in that same sub after the "ColumnNameAList.DataBind()" line. I assumed that since I am modifying the listview after databinding that those changes would be kept.

Comment: The custom sub I mentioned above resides in the Page_PreRender area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I could only reliably solve this with a codebehind solution.
I made a copy of the original datasource, modified my copy and then databound to it.

```
Dim MyOriginalTableSource As Data.DataView = DataManager.example()
Dim ModifiedTable As DataTable = MyOriginalTableSource.ToTable
'do stuff here
Mylistbox.DataSource = ModifiedTable
Mylistbox.DataBind()
```

Won't work for everyone, but in this case it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a couple of issues with the way you are approaching this, including that the ListView is already databound and that you are both adding and inserting the newItem.

When we have a scenario like this, we take one of two approaches:

1) Add the new item to the data source before the source is data bound.

2) Remove databinding and manually create each of the list view items, then add your new item at the beginning or end of the loop.

Comment: Looks like I will have to follow approach #2 and add them manually because I am trying to insert items and change the list order.  Do you have any concise examples of how to do the postbacks if you manually create a list of items in a listview?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it would be to inject it into the sql.

```
select col1, col2, col3 from table1 union select '1','2','3'
```

this would ensure that the item is always added, and asp.net doesn't need to know or care.

You can add this into the sql query or add it from the behind code before binding query. if you are not binding with sql, you can also do this to any list item with LINQ